# Bundled JRE is not installed or updated

Tags: install4j

We have two applications that have Windows installers with bundled JRE option. Both installers are built in Bamboo and currently install4j 7.0.9 is used. First application (Openfire) updates bundled JRE when installing new version on top with newer JRE included. But second application (Spark) has a few issues:

1. Minor issue. It is not installing bundled JRE folder if there is JRE/JDK installed on a system. First application (Openfire) is not doing the same and always installs JRE, even if system JRE/JDK is present.
2. Second application (Spark) is not updating installed JRE folder when installing newer version on top with newer JRE included.

I can't figure out why second application behaves like that. It either started after we have switched to newer install4j version or after going from Ant to Maven build. install4j installer xml used in Bamboo is old (has 6.1.4 version in it). Maybe it is missing some option for the latest install4j version. https://github.com/igniterealtime/Spark/blob/master/distribution/src/installer/spark.install4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On the "Bundled JRE" step of the configuration wizard for Windows media files, there is a "Install only if no other suitable JRE" check box which may be selected.
2. The "Install files" action has a "Update bundled JRE" property which may be deselected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like 1. is responsible for both issues and changing in xml installOnlyIfNecessary="true" to "false" fixed them.